# Closing File Handle (Resource) with Jena

Tags: jena

I wonder how Jena handle resource closing. For instance when readying a model in-memory from a file, Where is the code, that does the closing of the file, once the model is in memory ?

Can someone point me to a code or any doc that explain, the resource (file) management strategy of Jena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser code is `org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser`.

If the app code passes in a `InputStream`, it is responsible for closing it, e.g. using try-with-resources.

If a parser opens an `InputStream`, it closes it.

If you think there is a bug, please [file a JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA) with a complete, minimal example.

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. I found IO.close here and there, so figured it was doing the job, although was not sure in the case, of supplying the inputStream myself. That shorten my investigation :) !!!